# Error: You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, pycharm

Links for screenshots

- Settings.py

  - http://postimg.org/image/83120pd9p/
  - http://postimg.org/image/tkdnc9qgd/
  - http://postimg.org/image/qsu56cpj5/
  - http://postimg.org/image/cwz0cnf1v/
  - http://postimg.org/image/u193rlac3/
- Manage

  - http://postimg.org/image/qpikg5gbj/
- Wsgi

  - http://postimg.org/image/t2pdzffvv/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not a question

Comment: if you're simply trying to get your app running, get rid of the load_env call and runserver from command line using python manage.py runserver command. pls check django tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: But i want to run debugger in my PyCharm and that is not working. Same error is coming. And i have removed load_env from manage.py. So please help me in that.

Answer (score 5):

You should have something like this in your manage.py file which loads your settings.py.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "core.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    load_env()
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Just make sure that settings.py file is mapped properly in the manage.py.

Your attachment only shows the init__.py. Please put the screenshots of the other files too.

Hoping that you have not made any changes in the manage.py. BTW i could have written this in the comment section but do not have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Error: name 'load_env' is not defined coming how to correct it. Please help in it.

Comment: SIr, i have added all screenshots of my django app like settings.py, manage.py and wsgi.py. Please check it.

Comment: I find a screenshot of the settings.py only.

Comment: Sorry, i made a hyperlink of all first links. Now i defined each and every screenshot and their links now please check it.

Comment: Are you loading any application settings from environment. Do you have a .env file?

Comment: In Pycharm I think that you have to set the Env Variables as follows.                                                                                Go to Run -> Edit Configurations, select your project on the right of the window from Debug Configuration. You will see Environment variables on the right, set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=sstream.settings there.

Comment: Sir, as you said i did but  Error: AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. coming.

Comment: Are you sure that the 'corsheader' app is available in your project/ evironment? install all the packages from requirements.txt and Try removing the 3rd party apps one by one and check if it works.